Color animation is bugged svg
I have a problem because I am learning about svg and I have made a basic animation but I want to fill the second rectangle with a gradient. The colour of the second rectangle is always grey or black, no matter what colour I change to even I can type red directly and it will still be grey. Anyone know why this is happening?
<svg width="650" height="490" viewBox="0 -27 415 190" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <defs>
                          <linearGradient id="ss" gradientTransform="rotate(63)">
                            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(230,67,22);" />
                            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(101,32,70);" />
                          </linearGradient>
                      
                          <mask id="mask1">
                            <rect x="-445" y="0" width="445" height="190" fill="white">
                              <animate attributeName="x" values="-445; 0; 0; 445" keyTimes="0; 0.4; 0.8; 1" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                            </rect>
                            <rect x="-445" y="0" width="85" height="190" fill="url(#ss)">
                              <animate attributeName="x" values="-445; -445; 445; 445" keyTimes="0; 0.4; 0.8; 1" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                            </rect>
                          </mask>
                        </defs>
                      
                        <path d="M140 20C73 20 20 74 20 140c0 135 136 170 228 303 88-132 229-173 229-303 0-66-54-120-120-120-48 0-90 28-109 69-19-41-60-69-108-69z" fill="white" mask="url(#mask1)"/>
                      </svg>

I have no idea why this is happening.
I will be very happy if someone can help.
Thank you in advance!

You are using the gradient inside the mask. This will define the alpha (transparency) of the mask. If you need to see the gradient, use it as a fill for the path

Can you explain what the goal is? What about the path? Should it have the gradient and if so, then how should it be masked?

It shouldn't have, I wanted only the rect that goes through to have a gradient in the colors I wanted @chrwahl

Try remove mask from defs.
<svg width="650" height="490" viewBox="0 -27 415 190" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="ss" gradientTransform="rotate(63)">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(230,67,22);" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(101,32,70);" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="-445" y="0" width="445" height="190" fill="white">
    <animate attributeName="x" values="-445; 0; 0; 445" keyTimes="0; 0.4; 0.8; 1" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
  <rect x="-445" y="0" width="85" height="190" fill="url(#ss)">
    <animate attributeName="x" values="-445; -445; 445; 445" keyTimes="0; 0.4; 0.8; 1" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
</svg>

